# Hosting data on datahub.io: "OpenData StackExchange" organization

Tags: discussion

We recently created an organization on datahub.io: **[OpenData StackExchange](http://datahub.io/organization/opendata-stackexchange)**. This was necessary for publishing data sets that are based on discussions here.

Anyone can follow, but if you'd like to become a member, please follow these steps:

1. make an account at [datahub.io](http://datahub.io/) (if you don't have one already)
2. add a comment or answer below with your username from that site
3. please indicate if you'd like to be an admin.

Comment: p.s. I chose datahub.io over github because to upload a file, github requires installing software.

Answer (score 2):

i would love to be both, but don't want to trample on anyone's feet. member is fine, admin is killer
http://datahub.io/user/jalbertbowdenii

Comment: done. thanks for your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for doing this Phil! I'd love to help out.  Let me know what you need.  User name: jeanne_holm and http://datahub.io/user/jeanne_holm

Comment: Thanks. I made you an admin. Let me know if you want to be a regular member instead (demotion)

Answer (score 2):

Would love to be a contributor and an admin to this organization.

Username: **rao**

Link: http://datahub.io/user/rao

Thanks for creating this.

ps: I also think datahub.io is a better choice than github.

Comment: You're added as an admin. Feel free to start adding data!